# Android SDK installation is not found in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

Android SDK is successfully installed, but when I enter the location address to the Xamarin Studio settings, it says "No SDK found at the specified location."

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

How can I make sure the Android SDK installation process goes right and the files are not incomplete or anything?

Comment: Provide cleaner title and wording

Comment: Xamarin Studio has been deprecated for quite a while now